# $('#modalBusy').dialog('close') not working on properly with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am working with JQuery dialog which is opened before an ajax call and on returning from the ajax call the dialog('close') is executed. below statement opens up the busy dialog box as a banner (with no ok or cancel option):

```
$('.updateActionsTasks').live('click', function ()
{$('#modalBusy').html('<span>Busy...Please Wait.</span>').dialog({ dialogClass: 'no-close', resizable: false, width: 100, height: 100, modal: true, title: 'Busy' });  
More code goes here ...
//Ajax function call goes here
```

However, the close method work correctly only once. Upon executing the click again, the dialog opens up but never gets closed. The line with tag 'COMM' executes but does not close the dialog from second time execution on wards.

```
function ActionWorklistItem(serviceUrl, worklistActionItems, actionName, ActiveTab) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: serviceUrl,
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        var xml;
        if (typeof data == "string") {
            xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xml.async = false;
            xml.loadXML(data);
        } else {
            xml = data;
        }
        var xmlText = $(xml).text();
        xmlObj = $.parseXML(xmlText);
        if ($(xmlObj).find('IsSuccess').text() == 'true') {
            $('#modalBusy').dialog('close'); //COMM: This always executes
            __doPostBack($('.upWorklistCtrlID').val(), ActiveTab);
        } else {
            $('#modalBusy').dialog('close');
            //Create error msg dialog           }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#modalBusy').dialog('close');
        //Create error msg dialog
    }
});
```

Comment: The last curly-bracket in your `success` callback function is being commented-out by: `//Create error msg dialog`. Unless this is a copy/paste error, move the `}` character to the next line.

Comment: Yes that was a copy paste error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following line seems to have done the trick.

```
$('#modalBusy').dialog('destroy').remove();
```

Comment: This is wasteful and not preferred. See Jasper's correct answer. The correct way is to create the dialog once and then open and close it as required. Not to go through the process of creating and destroying another dialog each time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of initializing the dialog each click, initialize it once and then just open it when the link is clicked:

```
$('#modalBusy').html('<span>Busy...Please Wait.</span>').dialog({ autoOpen : false, dialogClass: 'no-close', resizable: false, width: 100, height: 100, modal: true, title: 'Busy' });
$('.updateActionsTasks').live('click', function () {  
    $('#modalBusy').dialog('open');
```

The `autoOpen : false` option will make it so the dialog does not open when it's initialized.

Comment: If I Initialize the dialog outside (i.e. on document.ready), the dialog never open up